# Is there an adverb in English, meaning "with an interest"?

Tags: meaning

I would like to translate in English a Chinese phrase, whose literal meaning is "to do some action, led by an interest in some goal". On this account, I have been wondering whether there exists an English adverb that expresses the meaning "with an interest"?

For example:

*He is an expert in the field that I have a problem with, so I am expecting his talk "with a great interest"...*

or:

*I researched your company "with an interest" and thus I came across your advert for ...*

PS: The phrase, I am struggling to translate, means something along the lines of "If you want your life to be beneficial, live *with an interest*" (i.e. have an interest in something, follow some goals, seek, etc).

Comment: The word *interest* in English has various meanings, but there are two important ones. First, if I was a keen spotter of different kinds of birds and I went away every week-end with camera and binoculars, you could say that I had *an interest in bird-watching*. Another type of interest is a financial/ business or similar type of *interest*. If I own shares in a company which is hoping to win a major contract, you could say that I had *an interest* in the contract being placed. Think about those two kinds of *interest* for a moment and see if that helps you. I am here if you want more help.

Comment: The word that comes to mind for me is "pertinent" or "pertinence". It doesn't precisely fit but it's close. https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=pertinent+definition

Answer (score 13):

[*Eagerly*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eagerly) is probably the word you are looking for. It's more common in everyday usage than *ardently*.

Comment: There's probably also something about the word *ardently* that just doesn't look or sound aesthetically very pleasing these days, in addition to being much more rarely understood now; it may just be my perception though.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the most obvious choice is **interestedly**.

> > In an interested manner; through self-interest; with interest or concern.
> >
> > 1886   R. Broughton Dr. Cupid I. vii. 114   "A figure whose manœuvres are interestedly watched by the rest of the company."

(http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97739)

I admit that the clash of so many alveolar consonants at the end of the word sounds rather clumsy.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of words that might work, but I'd suggest *ardently*, which is defined by oxforddictionaries.com as "very enthusiastic or passionate".

One alternative suggested by that definition itself might be *enthusiastically*.  *Enthusiasm* is defined by that same website as "intense and eager enjoyment, interest, or approval".

Comment: "Ardently" might suggest a little too much enthusiasm - I feel like it connotes just a hint of sexual excitement.

Comment: Sex sells... : )

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest "ardently," as it least implies great enthusiasm, which I don't believe is what you're going for.  Perhaps "avidly" - although this also suggests enthusiasm - or "keenly," as this, at least to me, suggests "sharpness" rather than enthusiasm.

Answer (score 2):

You say at the end there that you are trying to translate the phrase "live with an interest", but for "interest" you are seeking a word which means "have an interest in something, follow some goals, seek, etc". From that qualification, it's clear that what you need isn't a direct translation for the word "interest", but the appropriate English word for that sense of its meaning in Chinese.

I believe what you need is a fairly common English phrase - ["live with purpose"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live%20with%20purpose%22), or ["live purposefully"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live%20purposefully%22). If you look at the Google results for those phrases, I think you'll find they're discussing the same concept which you seek to translate. Both phrases have [greatly increased in popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live%20with%20purpose%2C%20live%20purposefully&year_start=1915&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3) in recent years, and should be familiar to most English-speakers who would be receptive to the statement you're translating.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a word that covers the full range of meaning for the two examples you gave, *with great personal interest* and *having an interest in something, following some goals, seeking, etc.*. Here are my suggestions individually:

> He is an expert in the field that I have a problem with, so I am __________ expecting his talk.

- [*eagerly*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eagerly) : very excited and interested : feeling a strong and impatient desire to do something or for something
- with much [*anticipation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anticipation) : a feeling of excitement about something that is going to happen : the act of preparing for something
- with [*bated breath*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bated+breath) : the condition of waiting for something to happen; subdued breathing due to high emotions

> If you want your life to be beneficial, live __________.

- [*purposefully*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purposefully) : having a purpose, as *a* meaningful, *b* intentional : full of determination
- *for a purpose* - this has a slightly different connotation than *purposefully*, suggesting that one has a high-level goal that one conforms all of one's actions to the service of.
- [*intentionally*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intentionally) : done in a way that is planned or intended
- [*deliberately*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliberately) :  characterized by or resulting from careful and thorough consideration
- with [*gusto*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gusto) : enthusiastic and vigorous enjoyment or appreciation : vitality marked by an abundance of vigor and enthusiasm
- [*wholeheartedly*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wholeheartedly) :  completely and sincerely devoted, determined, or enthusiastic : marked by complete earnest commitment : free from all reserve or hesitation
- [*boldly*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boldly) : assured, confident (possibly archaic)

You might also be interested in the phrase [*carpe diem*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carpe%20diem) : the enjoyment of the pleasures of the moment without concern for the future

You might also like to look up *passionate*, *fervent*, *zealous*, *enthusiastic*.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is already an almost perfect use of the phrase "with great interest":

- > He is an expert in a field related to my problem, so I am awaiting his talk **with great interest**.

I can't come up with a good description of where this phrase works and doesn't work, but here are some more usage examples that sound right to me.

- > I read her letter with great interest, hoping for more news of the expedition.
- > We had more of a stake in the Church's decision than our neighbors could have imagined, and we followed the debate with great interest.

Answer (score 0):

Some other options you might consider are:

**Curiously** which Dictionary.com defines as

> eager to learn or know; inquisitive.

**Inquisitively** which Dictionary.com defines as

> given to inquiry, research, or asking questions; eager for knowledge;
>   intellectually curious: an inquisitive mind. 2. unduly or
>   inappropriately curious; prying.

**Intently** which google defines as

> with earnest and eager attention.